# What does playing "Ranked" mean?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

I play Starcraft and today someone asked me if I had ever played 'ranked'.

What does that mean?

Comment: A quick Google would have found you the answer and on top of that, looking at the games main interface would have also found you the answer.

Comment: Are you talking about starcraft 2, or about starcraft?

Answer (score 5):

That person was asking you if you have ever played against other people for a place in a leaderboard. Starcarft 2 has a ladder system. You get into leagues and you increase your rank by winning matches, or decrease it by losing them. Think of it as a permanent tournament going on.

If you perform well you are promoted to a higher league. If you don't, you are demoted. There are 7 leagues per each mode.

- Bronze
- Silver
- Gold
- Platinum
- Diamond
- Master
- Grandmaster

With modes like 1vs1, 2vs2, and so on. Grandmaster is 1vs1 only though.